# Compiling using gcc compiler inside docker/singularity image from outside

Tags: docker, gcc, singularity-container

I want to use `gcc` in docker/singularity image to compile a program. Using local gcc, I use `gcc tc.c -I PATH_TO_LIB` without any error. To use the `gcc` in the image,  I use the following command line.

`singularity exec gcc_5.1.0.sif gcc tc.c -I PATH_TO_LIB`

But the problem is that gcc cannot find the .h file in the library path. It returns the following error.

```
fatal error: csmith.h: No such file or directory
#include "csmith.h"
```

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I used `singularity pull docker://gcc:5.1.0` to download the image.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the directory containing the missing header file?

Comment: I solved the issue. It seems that there was a bug in the singularity version that I have been using. I upgraded it and the problem was resolved.